# How can I check number is can divide only by 2 prime number that I input

Tags: c, loops

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdbool.h>
#include<math.h>
int prime(int num_p, int num_q, int num_n);
int check_prime(int num);
int main(){
    int num_prime1, num_prime2, num;
    scanf("%d %d %d",&num_prime1, &num_prime2, &num);
    prime(num_prime1, num_prime2, num);
}
int check_prime(int num){
    bool check=true;
    int i;
    for(i=2;i<(sqrt(num));++i){
        if(num%i==0){
            check = false;
        }
    }
    return check;
}
int prime(int num_p, int num_q, int num_n){
    int i, count=0;
    if(check_prime(num_p)==true && check_prime(num_q)==true){
        for(i=0; i<num_n; ++i){
            if((i%num_p==0) && (i%num_q==0)){
                if(i>count)count = i;               
            }
        }
    }
    printf("%d",count);
}
```

'''This is my code I want to find a most number that only 2prime number can divide it

> Ex: input:3, 5 ---> prime_number
>
> ......input:100 ---> range number i want to find most number that only 2prime number can divide it
>
> output:75 ---> (75 not 90 because 2 can divide 90 not only 3,5

how can i do?'''

Comment: but now out put is 90

Comment: `for(i=2;i<(sqrt(num));++i)` calls `sqrt` on every iteration, but `num` does not change so neither does `sqrt`. So this is very inefficient.

Comment: `if((i%num_p==0) && (i%num_q==0))` will only be true if either `num_p%num_q==0` or `num_q%num_p==0` and `i>num_p` and `i>num_q`, so `num_n>` than these. Your brute force method can be improved when using math.

Comment: If a number can **only** be divided  by `n` and `m` (where `n` and `m` are prime), then that number is `n * m`. Any other number will have other factors.